# Doesn't or wouldn't?

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

Here is my phrase from Stack Overflow question.

> How to create a universal function so that it doesn't have to be rewritten for every new polynomial degree NN?

Could (would, should, arrrgh) I write instead "so that it wouldn't have to be ... ?

Comment: Either is fine.  There's perhaps a subtle difference in nuance, which makes no difference in this context.  You can even use "shouldn't" for a slightly difference emphasis on "correctness".

Comment: Thank you. Finally a phrase in English that I wrote correctly.

Comment: Stick with "doesn't" or "won't" there. They're more common.

Comment: _Doesn't_, _wouldn't_ and _won't_ have the same meaning in this context. _Shouldn't_ implies that it might still need to be rewritten, so I would stick with one of the others.

Comment: Note that what you quoted isn't a proper sentence (regardless of the alternatives of *doesn't*). In your question, all three options (*could*, *would*, *should*) are valid, but mean entirely different things.

Comment: @userr2684291 Tell me please, what's wrong in my sentence?

Comment: @MichaelO. It doesn't ask the "how" question properly. It should start "How do you create...". "How to..." is used when making statements, not questions.

Comment: @SteveES By itself, it can be used as a title of a tutorial or something, but otherwise you'd use it in a sentence such as this one: *Tell me how to do it* or *She told me how to do it*, or *How to do it is what I don't understand*, etc.

Comment: @userr2684291 Sorry, I think I phrased that badly. I meant that "how to..." is not in and of itself used to form a question, it is used as an explanation in a sentence. To form a "how" question you need to use an auxiliary verb after _how_, e.g. "how do..." and "how can...".

Comment: Simplify, simplify, simplify! _"How can I create a universal function that doesn't have to be rewritten for every new polynomial degree NN?"_ Even simpler: _"How can I create a universal function that need not be rewritten for every new polynomial degree NN?"_ Presto, you don't need any conditionals!

Answer (score -1):

Let's break it down.

> "How to create a universal function so that it doesn't (does not) have to be 
>       rewritten for every new polynomial degree NN?"

This works fine.

> "How to create a universal function so that it would'nt (would not) have to 
>       be rewritten for every new polynomial degree NN?"

This is less appropriate as you are using a conditional tense. Either works, but doesn't would work better in your case.

Comment: (–1) Explain the difference between the two variants at least, please.

Comment: Using "wouldn't" implies a strong possibility that someone *would* want to rewrite it -- which is completely justified, and the reason for creating a "universal" function.  Saying it's "less appropriate" suggests that you don't understand this context.